# C++11 for loop through vector of unique_ptr

Tags: c++11, for-loop, iterator, stdvector, unique-ptr

Having trouble correctly looping through a vector of unique_ptrs to my own custom object.  I've provided pseudo-code below which isn't fully fleshed out, but focus on the for loop.  I'd like to use the C++11 "for" loop, and iterate over the vectors - OR from what I've heard, providing your own iterators is better?  I just don't know how to do this when I have separate classes.  If I'm keeping the vector in a manager class, then where should I define the iterator methods?  In the object class, or the manager class?  I also want to make sure that my data stays const, so the actual values aren't able to be changed.

```
// Class for our data
Class GeoSourceFile
{
    // some data, doesn't matter
    double m_dNumber;
    int    m_nMyInt;
}
// singleton manager class
Class GsfManager
{
  public:
    // Gets pointer to the vector of pointers for the GeoSourceFile objects
    const std::vector<std::unique_ptr<GeoSourceFile>>* GetFiles( );
  private:
    // Vector of smart pointers to GeoSourceFile objects
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<GeoSourceFile>> m_vGeoSourceFiles;  
}
void App::OnDrawEvent
{
    GsfManager* pGsfMgr = GsfManager::Instance();
    for(auto const& gsf : *pGsfMgr->GetFiles() )
    {
         oglObj->DrawGeoSourceFile( file );
    }
}

void OglClass::DrawGeoSourceFile( std::unique_ptr<GeoSourceFile> file )
{
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer to my issues myself.

Important thing to remember here is that you cannot create a copy of a unique_ptr... this includes passing the pointer to other functions.  If you pass the unique_ptr to another function, then you must use the & character in the receiving function.

For example:

```
void OglClass::DrawGeoSourceFile( const std::unique_ptr<GeoSourceFile> file )
{
    // fails to compile, you're getting a copy of the pointer, which is not allowed
}

void OglClass::DrawGeoSourceFile( const std::unique_ptr<GeoSourceFile>& file );
{
    // successfully compiles, you're using the original pointer
}
```